# I can't set up luarocks on Windows 10

Tags: lua, luarocks

As the title says I can't setup luarocks on Windows 10, I downloaded the single binary, which has luarocks.exe, and luarocks_admin.exe, I ran both programs and a console windows appeared and then quickly dissapeared, when I try to install a package ie. `luarocks install lpeg` I get`

```
'luarocks' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

the installation instructions for Win 10 (https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows) do not have anything to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

where did you setup luarocks? From your text I'd say you only downloaded the executable and ran it.

You need to add the location of the luarocks executable to your PATH environment variable so Windows can find it when you enter the command `luarocks` in the console.